# How to use CMake only built for armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface

I use cmake build library for armeabi-v7a. However, the following error comes:

```
 Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/xingyugu/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/xingyugu/Desktop/Hello_jni/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/mips64 --target native-lib}
  ninja: error: 'src/main/jniLabs/armeabi-v7a/mips64/libkface.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/mips64/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

I only want to build for armeabi-v7a instead of mips. How could solve this problem? THX!

Comment: BTW, the libkface.so only support armeabi-v7a.

Comment: Look for "Specify ABIs" on https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: In app gradle file defaultConfig {
 cmake {
  cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
    }
} it will create one .so file. Before that delete **cmake** folder in **.externalNativeBuild** folder inside **app** folder.